# Sending Image to MobileApp in another server

Tags: java, android, ios, image, mobile

One of our core system has been integrated with a mobile app recently where we need to share images which are kept in our repository to Mobile app which is residing in another server in the same network. When we analysed solution

1. Send image as byte[] over the api which is getting used to call
2. Host image in one of the container we are running and share the image url over api

Which one is the right approach to go on with, or is there any other approach on which we can have a better solution ?

Comment: Sending to a mobile app on another server? What kind of setup would that be? Dont understand a word.

Comment: Its some thing like you are the centralised system for services/programs across different channels(medium of communication can be web,mobile-app,sms,email) and the client system(i take example of mobile app) uses of one of your services to execute a particular program

Comment: Sorry, still dont understand a word. Come to the point please.

Answer (score 0):

1.Upload image into server using mutipart.

2.Save image into server and make the path of it.

3.You can use then anywhere this byte of path.

Hope it helps